# Tensors and Special Relativity

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a textbook that covers, at least for a large part, special relativity with tensors/a geometrical approach. Most textbooks I have found develop tensors for the purposes of GR; I'd like a book that goes through this exercise for the purposes of understanding SR. I'll then feel more comfortable moving on with the GR bit.

Ideally, the textbook/resource will first cover tensors, and then move on to discuss tensor analysis in SR.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The Classical Theory of Fields by Landau & Lifshitz takes this approach.

Answer (score 0):

One resource that introduces tensors purely for special relativity would be Professor Susskind's lectures on the subject (notes found here: http://www.lecture-notes.co.uk/susskind/special-relativity/lecture-6/tensors/)

Although these notes don't introduce tensors rigorously as mathematical objects in there own right, they give you exactly what you need to study SR.

Comment: Hello. Would you have any dedicated book in mind? Plus, any math book that introduces tensors?